# Launching pyspark webui on local mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I view the `pyspark` WEB UI in `local` mode from a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your pyspark application, web UI is available on localhost:4040. You should be able to access it from browser - http://localhost:4040/